# Cat Tourist Attractions In Japan

Tags: japan, pets

For some reason, the Japanese are really fond of cats.
For example, recently I found out that a station master in Japan is a cat named [Tama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tama_%28cat%29)!

[image: Tama]

Are there any other tourist attractions in Japan related to cats (Preferably near Tokyo)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Being in Japan, anything cute you ask for will most likely exist in
>   much more animation formats than real life versions. So be prepared
>   for a definite shortage of real cats here.

While there are 2 cat-themed amusement parks, [one a bit far](http://www.harmonyland.jp/english/harmony/harmony.html) away from Tokyo and [one a bit closer](http://www.puroland.co.jp/english/access.html) (this stuff is not only reserved for [mice](http://www.tokyodisneyresort.co.jp/en/tdl/)), there are also several occasions where cats play a part in Japanese culture and are very well worth visiting, even if you do not like cats!

- The [Nemuri-Neko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemuri-neko) in the [Nikko Tosho-gu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikk%C5%8D_T%C5%8Dsh%C5%8D-g%C5%AB) shrine (which also features some famous monkeys), not too far from Tokyo
  [image]
- The omni-present [Maneki-neko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maneki_Neko) which can be seen and bought as souvenirs all over Japan,
  [image]
- The [Bakeneko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakeneko), which is a form or the Maneki-Neko and has a Temple in Setagaya called [Gotokuji](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tokyo/Setagaya) with tons of cat statues, apparently the origin of the Maneki-Neko, but another shrine, [Imado Jinja](http://ilove.cat/en/3424), claims the same for itself.
- The [Nekomata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nekomata) figures, you might find in museums or libraries, or in tons of new and old books at [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.jp/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=%E7%8C%AB%E5%8F%88)
- From the movie "[My Neighbor Totoro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catbus)" exists a "[catbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catbus)" which can be bought as a plush animal [online](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002YN35I) and offline (Famous [kiddyland](http://www.kiddyland.co.jp/en/images/hara_map_640.gif) in Harajuku has all of it)
  [image]
- From the movie "[Kiki's delivery service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiki%27s_Delivery_Service)" comes another famous cartoon cat. Both this one and the catbus above might be available at the "[Ghibli Museum](http://www.ghibli-museum.jp/en/)"

[image]

- [Hikone Castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikone_Castle) has a "[Samurai Cat](http://hikone-hikonyan.jp/)"

[image]

- More online than offline, the Youtube celebrity "[Maru](http://sisinmaru.blog17.fc2.com/)" should be mentioned for completeness.
- For real live cat overdose visit [Cat Island](http://www.tofugu.com/2010/11/09/cat-island-japan/), also called [Tashirojima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tashirojima) where they even have a cat shrine
- There is a [cat street](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Attraction_Review-g1066456-d610349-Reviews-Cat_Street-Shibuya_Tokyo_Tokyo_Prefecture_Kanto.html) in Tokyo, which is however misleading, but still a nice shopping area.
- There are (among other, weirder types) [Cat Cafes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_caf%C3%A9) in Tokyo, for example one in [Ikebukuro](http://www.nekorobi.jp/english/map.html) and [many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=cat%20cafe%20tokyo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).
- [Here is](http://www.catsparella.com/2013/03/around-world-in-80-cats-27-japan.html) another cat-fan report from Japan

Comment: When I lived in Tokyo, I remember all of these.  I have fond memories of the Nikko Tosho-gu shrine listed above.  It is definitely well worthwhile to have a look at it.

Comment: There is a nearly full sized cat bus in the Ghibli Museum: http://www.ghibli-museum.jp/en/welcome/004539.html